# Informative features are not returning Cyrillic characters

Tags: python, nltk, feature-extraction, python-unicode

I've switched Python 3.6 now, but when running informative features I end up with gibberish when trying to print Russian in my feature extractor.

```
Most Informative Features
  three_last_letters = 'Ð¾Ì'            noun : verb   =      6.6 : 1.0
  three_last_letters = 'Ð³Ð'            noun : verb   =      5.4 : 1.0
  three_last_letters = 'ÐµÐ'            noun : verb   =      4.7 : 1.0
  three_last_letters = 'Ð¼Ð'            noun : verb   =      4.4 : 1.0
  three_last_letters = 'Ð½Ñ'            noun : verb   =      3.5 : 1.0
```

In the case of the feature extractor itself

```
def POS_features(word):
    return{'three_last_letters':word[-3:]}
print(POS_features(u'Богатир'))
```

I can get тир to print just fine, is there something I can do to make the informative features return Russian characters?

Comment: on what os? and do you try the print in a console or ide?

Comment: I code on the Jupyter notebook on Windows.

Comment: If this wasn't the case with Python 3.5, it could be because of this change: "PEP 528 and PEP 529, Windows filesystem and console encoding changed to UTF-8.". Sorry, don't have a proper solution but try to experiment with `sys.setdefaultencoding` and check `sys.stdout.encoding`.

Comment: What is your Jupyter notebook version?

Comment: Could you upload your training data sample or a pickle of your model somewhere so that we can download and help you debug?

Comment: @alvas version 4.3.1, also I'm still relatively new to coding and stackoverflow, what do you mean by a pickle?

Comment: @reivermello: [`pickle` is a serialization library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html).

Comment: What encoding are your input files? If your mangled output form a Jupyter notebook, or the windows command line?

Comment: @reivermello Instead of writing the solution into the question, write it as an actual answer below. That way you can mark something as accepted and close the thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what I'd done wrong,

```
vocab = nltk.corpus.reader.CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(
"C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data\\corpora\\russian\\vocab", r'.*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'^(noun|verb)', encoding="utf8"
```

when I'd imported my vocab folder, I'd encoded it as latin-1
all is well and Cyrillic characters were returned for me

```
 Most Informative Features
      three_last_letters = 'ать'            verb : noun   =     15.2 : 1.0
      three_last_letters = 'де'             noun : verb   =      2.6 : 1.0
      three_last_letters = 'сть'            noun : verb   =      1.5 : 1.0
      three_last_letters = 'пра'            noun : verb   =      1.4 : 1.0
      three_last_letters = 'ина'            noun : verb   =      1.4 : 1.0
```

Comment: note that you can use raw strings to write Windows paths (or any other string that contains backslashes) in Python source code. `r'C:\path\to\file'`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-l